# How to get all users in Role (Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework 2.0.0-beta1)?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I just updated to ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework 2.0.0-beta1 and got a compilation errors for my Roles classes. Maybe somebody can give me some clue how to get all users for a specific Role?

It's something very close, when I browse with Intellisense I am almost there, but need a tip :-).

This is how it worked before update:

```
 user.Roles.First().Role.Name.Equals("Admins")
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks like you are trying to access `IsInRole("Admins")`. If you must do this through EF, consider using `user.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Admins")`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its only exposed on the EF implementation layer so:

```
roleManager.FindByName("Admins").Users
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Kung! And Is there a more elegant way to get Admins from IdentityUserRole Table?

       `code(var userIds =  roleManager.FindByName("Admins").Users.Select(e => e.UserId).ToList();)
`
      var admins = userManager.Users.Where(e => userIds.Contains(e.Id));

Comment: Svitlana, did you find a more elegant way?  This seems like it should be an easy thing to do, but this is ugly.

Comment: I have a question. Why does the result of this only exposes the IdentityUserRoles properties, not of users? How do I see the User properties instead of the navigation table?

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer returns `CustomUserRoles`. If you are looking for the list of `ApplicationUsers`, try:

```
public IList<ApplicationUser> GetApplicationUsersInRole(string roleName)
{
    var selectedUserIds = from role in roleManager.Roles
                          where role.Name == roleName
                          from user in role.Users
                          select user.UserId;
    // this _users comes from the ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationUser
    return _users.Where(applicationUser => selectedUserIds.Contains(applicationUser.Id)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: :-).The only comment - I AM SO GLAD I SWITCHED TO ANGULAR/FIREBASE and do not need to carry that burden.... But thanks for your time, amigo.

Answer (score 8):

I really liked VahidN's solution, but I modified it a bit.  I made it into one query that uses the dbcontext.  This allows you to add additional clauses into the query (e.g. deleted, emailconfirmed, etc.)

```
public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetApplicationUsersInRole(string roleName)
{
      return from role in context.Roles
             where role.Name == roleName
             from userRoles in role.Users
             join user in context.Users
             on userRoles.UserId equals user.Id
             where user.EmailConfirmed == true
               && user.IsDeleted == false
             select user;
 }
```

Comment: I think even more streamlined is getting the role first, `var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);` and then querying, `var _usersInRole = role.Users.Select(j => context.Users.Where(k=> k.Id == j.UserId));` - That doesn't look as overwhelming as your query, but also, you can add additional queries to this as you did.