# Get list of users with assigned roles in asp.net identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have a drop down list box which lists roles. I want to get the list of users having that role. I mean list of users that are in "Administrator" role or "CanEdit" role. Here is my code:

```
public IQueryable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser> 
  GetRolesToUsers([Control] string ddlRole)
{    
  //ddlRole returns role Id, based on this Id I want to list users

  var _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
  IQueryable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser> query = _db.Users;

  if (ddlRole != null)
  {
    //query = query.Where(e => e.Claims == ddlRole.Value);  ???????              
  }

  return query;
}
```

Please help.

**Updated Code (still error)**

```
public List<IdentityUserRole> GetRolesToUsers([Control]string ddlRole)
{

  var roleManager = 
   new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
  var users = roleManager.FindByName("Administrator").Users.ToList();
  return users;
}
```

Error: The Select Method must return one of "IQueryable" or "IEnumerable" or "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser" when ItemType is set to "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser".

I tried various castings but none of them helped.

**UPDATE (working solution)**

Thanks to chris544, his idea helped me to fix this. Here is working method:-

```
public List<ApplicationUser> GetRolesToUsers([Control]string ddlRole)
{
  var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
  var users =
    context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(ddlRole)).ToList();

  return users;
}
```

Comment: Try Roles.GetUsersInRole(), you can get use default Role Provider API

Comment: @Larry you mean [string[] u = Roles.GetUsersInRole(ddlRole)] or [_roleManager.Roles.GetUsersInRole(ddlRole)]. First produces "The Role Manager feature has not been enabled" error and second no definition for "GetUserInRole". How I should use Roles.GetUsersInRole()?

Comment: Are you working on asp.net mvc 5? I'm currently working on 4. go to any action method and types "Roles" and it lives within "System.Web.Security" namespace.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET 4.5 and ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not an expert, but ...

There seemed to be no built in funcionality for this in Identity and I could not get it work from built in Roles also (it seems to not work with claims based Identity).

So I ended up doing something like this:

```
var users = context.Users        
    .Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(roleId))
    .ToList();
```

- `x.Roles.Select(y => y.Id)` gets a list of all role ids for `user x`
- `.Contains(roleId)` checks if this list of ids contains necessary `roleId`

Comment: There was no built in functionality for this in Identity 1.0, but it was expected in 2.0 somewhere on web i read this.

Comment: Thanks chris544, your idea helped me to fix this. I updated the question and i'm sure it will help many devs.

Comment: Been looking for an hour or so for a simple implementation. FINALLY found it. Thanks!

Comment: If the `Id` of the role is not known, should use an instance of `RoleManager` first.

Comment: y.Id should be y.RoleId

Answer (score 13):

I find the role by the role name input. After, I find list users by id of the role.

```
public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
{
 var roleManager = 
  new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new  ApplicationDbContext()));
 var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.First();
 var usersInRole = 
  Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(role.RoleId)).ToList();
 return usersInRole;
}
```

Comment: Great answer Trieu.  Provided reusable code in my opinion.  Short, concise, and flat out works!

Comment: I found out that @Trieu Doan was not corrent in my case, the code that worked was as following: 
`  var users = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.Select(x => x.UserId);
            var usersInRole = Users.Where(u => users.Contains(u.Id));`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to avoid using the context directly you can use the **RoleManager** with the following snippet

```
roleManager.FindByName("Administrator").Users
```

or

```
roleManager.FindByName("CanEdit").Users
```

For a short discussion about this topic have a look at the [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209093/how-to-get-all-users-in-role-microsoft-asp-net-identity-entityframework-2-0-0-b)

Comment: Thanks Horizon_Net..looks i'm very close to solution. Please check my updated code which produce error.

Comment: This returns a collection of `IdentityUserRole`s, not `ApplicationUser`s

Answer (score 4):

Using the RoleManager gives you this solution:

```
if(roleManager.RoleExists("CanEdit"))
{
    var idsWithPermission = roleManager.FindByName("CanEdit").Users.Select(iur => iur.Id);
    var users = db.Users.Where(u => idsWithPermission.Contains(u.Id));
}
```

I'd be interested to hear if this was better or worse than the other solutions here.

Comment: The only change I would make would be to wrap the above in an if statement to check if role exists.  if(roleManager.RoleExists("CanEdit")

Comment: +1 Going to the RoleManager (e.g. role table) is a much better shortcut than numerous LINQ queries that ultimately produce lots of SQL.

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways you can do it.

In the Controller current logged in user's role can be checked as follows,

```
  if(User.IsInRole("SysAdmin"))
        {
```

Outside Controller you can check whether a particular user belongs to a Role as follows:

```
 ApplicationUserManager UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roles = UserManager.GetRoles(userid);
        if (roles.Contains("SysAdmin"))
        {
        }
```

Do not forget to add namespace,

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

For some reasons like integration testing etc, you may directly want to use EF to find user's role as follows:

```
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var role = (from r in db.Roles where r.Name.Contains("Admin") select r).FirstOrDefault();
        var users = db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(role.Id)).ToList();
        if (users.Find(x => x.Id == userId) != null)
        {
            // User is in the Admin Role
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks
/dj
@debug_mode

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.Email` and add `UserName` or whatever was added to the `ASPNetUsers` for name.

```
private void AddAddminToMail(MailMessage message)
{
    var roles = db.Roles.Include(m => m.Users).Where(m => m.Name == "Admin").First();
    foreach (var user in roles.Users)
        {
            var id = user.UserId;
            var userEmail = db.Users.Find(id).Email;
            message.To.Add(userEmail);
        }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code working for me was as following:

```
  var users = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.Select(x => x.UserId);
  var usersInRole = Users.Where(u => users.Contains(u.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since bits like this tend to impact performance, I tried the other answers posted here and looked at the SQL they generated. This seems to be the most performant way of getting all the user's email addresses currently.

```
public void SendEmailToUsersInRole(string roleName)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    ...

    using (var usersDB = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var roleId = 
            usersDB.Roles.First(x => x.Name == roleName).Id;

        IQueryable<string> emailQuery =
            usersDB.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.RoleId == roleId))
                         .Select(x => x.Email);

        foreach (string email in emailQuery)
        {
            message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The SQL that it executes is shown below:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetRoles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE N'Reviewer' = [Extent1].[Name]

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]) AND ([Extent2].[RoleId] = @p__linq__0)
    )


-- p__linq__0: '3' (Type = String, Size = 4000)
```