# How can I get the list of all admins in MVC5 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to run a query using EntityFramework

```
   Get(u => u.Roles.Contains("Administrator"));
```

where the Get action is the same as the one from the tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I want to use it this way because I need it to go through the DbContext as it's just one line from the controller and I want to keep the consistency of the requests.

So my question is how do you do it and what is the best way to get all users with a specific role?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I ended up using:

```
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        string roleId = roleManager.FindByName("Administrator").Id;

        return Get(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(roleId));
```

Comment: So run it!! If you read your question through you should notice there isnt actually a question in it!!

Comment: It's the type of thing I want to run. I can't really run this because Contains does not accept a string. It accepts a Role object. And you are correct no actual question but my question is how do you do it and what is the best way to get all users with a specific role.

Comment: Do any of the proposed answers sufficiently answer your question? If not, is there any more information you can provide?

Comment: I have selected your answer as the correct one and up-voted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is close, but you'll need to look up the `RoleId` of the `Administrators` role first (because an `IdentityUserRole` doesn't have a `Name` property, unfortunately.)  Once you've gotten that, it's relatively simple.

In the example below I've nested another query to pull all users who's collection of `Roles` has at least one `IdentityUserRole` with a specific `RoleId`

```
// Add code to look up the appropriate RoleId below.
var roleId = 1; 

Get(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId));
```

If you're unsure how to perform the lookup, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22212506/1187982) on a related SO question

Comment: So what would be the best design to get the RoleID give I'm using UnitsOfWork design approach and inside the User's Repository I'm trying to get the admin users? (Basically the code I posted is inside the User's repository and I want to have a method that gives me all the admins.) Should I init a new object to find the RoleId there? Or is there a quicker way? Also I'm using ASP Identity.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio open right now so I can't verify this, but try this: `var administrators = RoleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == "Administrators").Users.ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `.Contains()` how it is intended to be used. Look at the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).ASPX

Doc says it  "Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element." Whether means T/F. It wont grab the users that have contain the specified role. You need to use a `.Where()` extension. It might look something like this:

```
var users = userRepo.Where(u => u.Roles.Contains(r => r.Name == "Administrator"));
```

So now, you are getting the users WHERE any of their roles CONTAIN a role with the name "Administrator"

Answer (score -1):

Try it with `U.Roles.Name == "Administrator"` or something like that?

Comment: Roles is of type ICollection<IdentityUserRole> so it does not contain a Name property. :/