# How to get list of user in a particular role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

How to get list of user in a particular role in ASP.net MVC5. I have following code but it returns all the user.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
  {
        var users = Context.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
  }
```

I have role name "Coordinator". I just want all the users with that role.

//View File

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Roles Listing </h2>
<div>
    <p><strong>Username | Email</strong></p>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <p>
            @user.UserName   |   @user.Email | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = user.Id })
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each user instance is of type ApplicationUser, and that you implemented Role Based authentication, you can easily filter user with specific roles like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        // Assuming that Coordinator has RoleId of 3
        var users = Context.Users.Where(x=>x.Roles.Any(y=>y.RoleId == 3)).ToList();
        return View(users);
}
```

Comment: Getting Following Error 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole' does not contain a definition for 'RoleName' and no extension method 'RoleName' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: see edit. You will need to find out the role id for coordinator.

Comment: Use the Role Manager, see this SO answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22212506/260079

Answer (score 0):

First create `ApplicationRoleManager` class to manage roles like below.

```
    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
            : base(roleStore)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        }
    }
```

Then add following code to Startup.Auth.cs class in order to create instance of RoleManager during owin start up.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

Your controller action should be like this.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
        var roleManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        var users = roleManager.FindByName("Coordinator").Users;

        return View(users);
  }
```

Hope this helps.