# How to convert this Linq query syntax to method syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29175319/295890) contained the following query:

```
var query = from role in _db.Roles
            where role.Name == roleName
            from userRoles in role.Users
            join user in _db.Users
            on userRoles.UserId equals user.Id
            select user;
```

How would I reproduce the same query using Linq method syntax?

Comment: step 1: use [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/). i think it can reproduce it for you.

Comment: [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net) can do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = _db.Roles
    .Where(role => role.Name == roleName)
    .SelectMany(role => role.Users)
    .Join(_db.Users, userRole => userRole.UserId, user => user.Id, (role, user) => user);
```

Some explanation

```
var query = from role in _db.Roles
        where role.Name == roleName // this will be translated to .Where
        from userRoles in role.Users // this is .SelectMany
        join user in _db.Users // this is .Join
        on userRoles.UserId equals user.Id // second and third arguments of .Join
        select user; // last argument of .Join
```

Comment: Am I missing something? That's a literal translation of the query, sure, but what's the point of the third line? Edit: does role really have a navigation property called Users that doesn't consist of Users?

Comment: As I understand from initial query (see "on userRoles.UserId equals user.Id" part) that Role has collection of UserRole {UserId, RoleId} objects.

Comment: @ChrisV also, it is not literal translation. The literal translation is in Ricky's answer.

Comment: @ChrisV original question is about AspNet Identity. See the sources: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityRole.cs#L52 and https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUserRole.cs

Answer (score 0):

This is the method syntax version

```
    var query =
        _db.Roles.Where(role => role.Name == roleName)
            .SelectMany(role => role.Users, (role, userRoles) => new {role, userRoles})
            .Join(_db.Users, @t => userRoles.UserId, user => user.Id, (@t, user) => user);
```

Comment: You dont need resultSelector with anonymous type on SelectMany, because you do use only userRoles from it.